# Concatenation result from MySQL query, using group and multiple tables

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct, concatenation, group-concat

I have some problem with MySQL query.

I have 5 tables (keys in brackets):

```
trips (tripId)
trips_moments (tripId, momentId)
moments (momentId)
moments_images (momentIs, imageId)
images (imageId)
```

In my situation I have 1 trip, which contains 2 moments, every moment contains 5 images.

I'd like in result to get in field "moments":

```
166;Kościuszko mound in Cracow;2012-11-08 15:38:14;6;F50MTTZK;jpg;6R2XJB9X|
167;Pope John Paul II (Jan Paweł 2) home town - Wadowice;2012-11-08 15:57:15;19;66B7VQ84;jpg;ILQYDQUC
```

instead of:

```
166;Kościuszko mound in Cracow;2012-11-08 15:38:14;6;F50MTTZK;jpg;6R2XJB9X|
166;Kościuszko mound in Cracow;2012-11-08 15:38:14;7;9PY1BZD1;jpg;TP7U07ST|
166;Kościuszko mound in Cracow;2012-11-08 15:38:14;8;VPGPFMMS;jpg;VF95BNNQ|
166;Kościuszko mound in Cracow;2012-11-08 15:38:14;9;EC7NL3HC;jpg;PD1CEQE6|
166;Kościuszko mound in Cracow;2012-11-08 15:38:14;10;8J1OT7IT;jpg;ZL8WAWCJ|
167;Pope John Paul II (Jan Paweł 2) home town - Wadowice;2012-11-08 15:57:15;19;66B7VQ84;jpg;ILQYDQUC|
167;Pope John Paul II (Jan Paweł 2) home town - Wadowice;2012-11-08 15:57:15;20;HZIPGJY7;jpg;FOOWJ8BV|
167;Pope John Paul II (Jan Paweł 2) home town - Wadowice;2012-11-08 15:57:15;21;9JOXXPJQ;jpg;ZIVJ5V7K|
167;Pope John Paul II (Jan Paweł 2) home town - Wadowice;2012-11-08 15:57:15;22;IS1JPW1N;jpg;31M4XVBM|
167;Pope John Paul II (Jan Paweł 2) home town - Wadowice;2012-11-08 15:57:15;23;OTOWNDZA;jpg;C03UFMBK
```

You can see in my result that record with 166 and 167 is repeated as many times as much images moment contains.

My current query:

```
 SELECT 
`t`.`tripId`, 
`t`.`title`, 
`t`.`when`, 
GROUP_CONCAT(
  DISTINCT(
    CONCAT(
       m.momentId, ';', m.title, ';', m.created, ';', i.imageId, ';', i.fileNameBase, ';', i.fileNameExtension, ';', i.directory)
    ) 
  SEPARATOR '|'
) AS `moments` 
FROM `trips` AS `t` 
LEFT JOIN `trips_moments` AS `tm` ON t.tripId = tm.tripId 
LEFT JOIN `moments` AS `m` ON tm.momentId = m.momentId 
LEFT JOIN `moments_images` AS `mi` ON m.momentId = mi.momentId 
LEFT JOIN `images` AS `i` ON mi.imageId = i.imageId 
WHERE (t.userId = '1') 
GROUP BY `t`.`tripId` 
ORDER BY `t`.`tripId` ASC
```

Current table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `images` (
  `imageId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `fileNameBase` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `fileNameExtension` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `directory` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `source` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`imageId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `moments` (
  `momentId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`momentId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `moments_images` (
  `momentId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `imageId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`momentId`,`imageId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trips` (
  `tripId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `when` date NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tripId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trips_moments` (
  `tripId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `momentId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tripId`,`momentId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: buy you have multiple imagees for each moment? you can't get your expected output. Doesn't all these 3 filename bases attached to 166: F50MTTZK, VPGPFMMS, 8J1OT7IT.

Comment: The result is correct, there are 5 images per moment. If you want to pick only one image, on which conditions should mysql pick a single image? the newest? the oldest? random?

Comment: @Kaii, I'd like to get the first image from rowset, if there is possibility to order them by name, or date, it would be perfect

Comment: @Nesim Razon, yes, for every moment there can be multiple images, but I just need to get one, as this is put on timeline with thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

I can't test right now, but this can give you an idea, I changes moemnt_images join like this:

```
LEFT JOIN `moments_images` AS `mi` ON m.momentId = mi.momentId  
AND imageId = (select min(imageId) from moments_images where momentId=m.momentId)
```

**full query:**

```
SELECT 
`t`.`tripId`, 
`t`.`title`, 
`t`.`when`, 
GROUP_CONCAT(
  DISTINCT(
    CONCAT(
       m.momentId, ';', m.title, ';', m.created, ';', i.imageId, ';', i.fileNameBase, ';', i.fileNameExtension, ';', i.directory)
    ) 
  SEPARATOR '|'
) AS `moments` 
FROM `trips` AS `t` 
LEFT JOIN `trips_moments` AS `tm` ON t.tripId = tm.tripId 
LEFT JOIN `moments` AS `m` ON tm.momentId = m.momentId 
LEFT JOIN `moments_images` AS `mi` ON m.momentId = mi.momentId  and imageId = (select min(imageId) from moments_images where momentId=m.momentId)
LEFT JOIN `images` AS `i` ON mi.imageId = i.imageId 
WHERE (t.userId = '1') 
GROUP BY `t`.`tripId` 
ORDER BY `t`.`tripId` ASC
```

Comment: It is working, thank you. I thought that there will need to do subquery, but hoped there is another solution without subquery. Thanks guys for your fast answers.

Answer (score 0):

@Kaii

I used this grouping by two columns, but results are not as expected:

In result I get two records with these values in field "moments":

1st record)

```
166;Kościuszko mound in Cracow;2012-11-08 15:38:14;9;EC7NL3HC;jpg;PD1CEQE6|
166;Kościuszko mound in Cracow;2012-11-08 15:38:14;6;F50MTTZK;jpg;6R2XJB9X|
166;Kościuszko mound in Cracow;2012-11-08 15:38:14;8;VPGPFMMS;jpg;VF95BNNQ|
166;Kościuszko mound in Cracow;2012-11-08 15:38:14;10;8J1OT7IT;jpg;ZL8WAWCJ|
166;Kościuszko mound in Cracow;2012-11-08 15:38:14;7;9PY1BZD1;jpg;TP7U07ST
```

2nd record)

```
167;Pope John Paul II (Jan Paweł 2) home town - Wadowice;2012-11-08 15:57:15;20;HZIPGJY7;jpg;FOOWJ8BV|
167;Pope John Paul II (Jan Paweł 2) home town - Wadowice;2012-11-08 15:57:15;22;IS1JPW1N;jpg;31M4XVBM|
167;Pope John Paul II (Jan Paweł 2) home town - Wadowice;2012-11-08 15:57:15;19;66B7VQ84;jpg;ILQYDQUC|
167;Pope John Paul II (Jan Paweł 2) home town - Wadowice;2012-11-08 15:57:15;21;9JOXXPJQ;jpg;ZIVJ5V7K|
167;Pope John Paul II (Jan Paweł 2) home town - Wadowice;2012-11-08 15:57:15;23;OTOWNDZA;jpg;C03UFMBK
```

I'd like to get one result as in my question, of course if possible.